# Subtracting milliseconds doesn't give expected result

Tags: java, date, datetime, grails, groovy

```
Date day1 = set_datetime(2017, Calendar.JUNE, 28, 8, 00, 0); 

Date day2 = set_datetime(2017, Calendar.JUNE, 28, 10, 00, 0);

def set_datetime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
        Date cal_date = cal.getTime();
        return cal_date
    }

println "\t\t (day2.getTime() - day1.getTime()) = " + (day2.getTime() - day1.getTime())
```

> `(day2.getTime() - day1.getTime()) = 7199996`

Something seems wrong here, because when I convert the milliseconds to hours, 7199996 isn't exactly 2 hours (7200000). In fact, it's 4 milliseconds less. Why isn't it 7200000 milliseconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not clearing out the milliseconds field.

Add

```
cal.clear();
```

before the `cal.set(...);` line, or add

```
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECONDS, 0);
```

---

More generally, don't use `java.util.Calendar` and `java.util.Date`: they are old, poorly-designed classes, fraught with well-known bugs.

Use classes from the `java.time` package, introduced in Java 8; or classes from [threetenbp](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) or JodaTime on earlier versions of Java.

Comment: Thank you. But I must use java 6, our low-end server

Comment: "or classes from threetenbp or JodaTime on earlier versions."

Answer (score 4):

In support of and as a modest supplement to the accepted answer, below is the ThreeTen-Backport version, which will work on Java 6.

```
LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JUNE, 28, 8, 0);
LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JUNE, 28, 10, 0);
System.out.println("\t\t (dateTime2 - dateTime1) = " 
            + Duration.between(dateTime1, dateTime2).toMillis());
```

It prints:

> `(dateTime2 - dateTime1) = 7200000`

Sorry I don’t have a Groovy/Grails environment running, so I have given you only Java code and will have to trust you to translate.

Your question is just one more about the outdated classes like `Calendar` that shows just one more example out of very many of how easily you get unexpected results from these and how little of a clue you’re often left with when this happens. Getting the ThreeTen-Backport for, in your case, Java 6 is certainly worth considering. In addition, the above code is also shorter, and in my opinion, clearer and more natural.

Comment: Thx, @Userthatisnotauser, for the improvement.